# Batch file and returning values from functions

Tags: windows, batch

I have a batch file that has multiple routines. examples

```
:checkFileExists
if not exist %1\%2 (
echo %2 does not exist under %1
set returnValue=FAIL
exit /b 1 
) 
exit /b 0 
:checkPortNumber 
if %1 LSS 1024 (
port number should be greater than 1024 and less than 65535
set returnValue=FAIL
exit /b 1 
)
... other checks for port number
exit /b 0 
... main code.. 
set returnValue=OK
call :checkFileExists c:\tmp
echo %returnValue% 
call :checkFileExists c:\tmp2
echo %returnValue% 
call :checkPortNumber 89
echo %returnValue%
```

c:\tmp is just an example and it exists. my return value correctly displays as OK. c:\tmp2 does not exist and my returnValue correctly displays as FAIL.

I do expect checkPortNumber to fail the test but returnValue is set to OK always. I have tried with setlocal enableDelayedExpansion also and not. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

This reordered/reworked/reformatted code behaves as expected.

Main problem with your code is that you only `set returnValue=OK` once at the beginning, if a subroutine `set returnValue=Fail` this does persist even if another sub does `exit /B 0`.

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\12\15\SU_1383774.cmd
@echo off
:: ... main code.. 

call :checkFileExists c:\tmp || Echo returned errorlevel %errorlevel%
echo %returnValue% 

call :checkFileExists c:\tmp2 || Echo returned errorlevel %errorlevel%
echo %returnValue% 

call :checkPortNumber 89 || Echo returned errorlevel %errorlevel%
echo %returnValue% 

Goto :Eof

:checkFileExists
if not exist "%~1\%~2" (
    echo %2 does not exist under %1
    set returnValue=FAIL
    exit /b 1 
) 
set returnValue=OK
exit /b 0 

:checkPortNumber 
if %1 LSS 1024 (
    echo port number should be greater than 1024 and less than 65535
    set returnValue=FAIL
    exit /b 1 
)
:: ... other checks for port number
set returnValue=OK
exit /b 0
```

Comment: It would be a better answer if you explained why this works when the original code doesn't.